# C# Concurrent Dictionary Object Read/Update Thread Safety Question

Tags: c#, .net-core, concurrentdictionary

In the code below I have a concurrent dictionary that i'm using for storing a single key/value pair where the value is a collection of strings.

I will be reading and updating the strings in this single key/value pair from different threads.

I'm aware that concurrent dictionaries are not entirely thread safe if one thread has changed a value before the other thread has perhaps finished reading it. But equally i'm not sure if string values really come into this topic or not, could someone please advise?

Its also worth mentioning that although I put this "GetRunTimeVariables" method into an interface for dependency injection, I actually cant use DI all the time for accessing this method due to the stages of app startup and OIDC events sign in/out where i need to access the dictionary values within classes that can't use dependency injection, so in essence I could be accessing this dictionary from nay means as necessary throughout the lifetime of the application.

Lastly i'm not really sure if there is any benefit in pushing this method into an interface, the other option is simply new up a reference to this class each time i need it, some thoughts on this would be appreciated.

```
public class RunTimeSettings : IRunTimeSettings
{
    // Create a new static instance of the RunTimeSettingsDictionary that is used for storing settings that are used for quick
    // access during the life time of the application. Various other classes/threads will read/update the parameters.
    public static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<int, RunTimeVariables> RunTimeSettingsDictionary = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, RunTimeVariables>();

    public object GetRunTimeVariables()
    {
        dynamic settings = new RunTimeVariables();

        if (RunTimeSettingsDictionary.TryGetValue(1, out RunTimeVariables runTimeVariables))
        {
            settings.Sitename = runTimeVariables.SiteName;                
            settings.Street = runTimeVariables.Street;
            settings.City = runTimeVariables.City;
            settings.Country = runTimeVariables.Country;
            settings.PostCode = runTimeVariables.PostCode;
            settings.Latitude = runTimeVariables.Latitude;
            settings.Longitude = runTimeVariables.Longitude;
        }

        return settings;
    }
}
```

Class for string values:

```
public class RunTimeVariables
{
    public bool InstalledLocationConfigured { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostCode { get; set; }
    public string Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Longitude { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `TryGetValue` is not thread safe, but it needs more investigation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-5.0#remarks)

Comment: One would have assumed 'try doing' something would surely be safer than saying 'do something' mmm, would be interested to learn more on this. Trying to understand official MS docs rarely helps

Comment: @ipinak ??? All it is thread safe. The only problem is if you try to do a `TryGetValue` and on failure do an explicit `Add`. The result of `TryGetValue` is valid only in the instant it is retrieved, and there is no guarantee it will be valid one instant before or one instant later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.String` type (the classical `string`s of C#) is immutable. No one can modify the "content" of a `String`. Anyone can make a property reference a *different* `String`.

But in truth the only problem you have here is that the various values could be de-synced. You have various properties that are correlated. If one thread is modifying the object while another thread is reading it, the reading thread could see some properties of the "old" version and some properties of the "new" version. This isn't a big problem if the object once written to the `ConcurrentDictionary` is not changed (is "immutable" at least as a business rule). Clearly a correct solution is to have `RuntimeVariables` be an immutable object (composed only of `readonly` fields that are initialized at instancing for example)

Comment: Hi, I don't understand the latter part of your explanation, but it might be worth me mentioning that this collection of string values is just being used for logging, so if there was a momentary inconstancy in values between one thread to the other, it would only affect 1qty log transaction. Do you think the use of my interface is pointless? Actually requires less lines of code just to new up the class when required...thx

Comment: @OJB1 Putting it in an interfaces will make it easier to mock it for unit testing, at least for classes that are unit-testable and where it is important that the values of the dictionary are set by the unit test/and/or it is impossible to load the values of the dictionary from normal sources (perhaps because the unit test doesn't have access to the db/to the remote server that has the values)

Comment: @obj1 What part of the explanation isn't clear? From which word to which word?

Comment: Your last sentence, could you please give an example of the correction i should make? thx

Comment: @OJB1 In C# 9.0 there will be a new feature, ["Init Only Setters"](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/init). Without C# 9.0 you would use the builder pattern, with a mutable class (like the `StringBuilder`) that has a method to create an immutable object (the `.ToString()` that returns a `string`). With an immutable object it is impossible that another thread changes the object while you are reading it. If it wants to change the object, it has to create a new object with the new values and then switch the object inside the dict.